# Pass a key-array to a Lotus-Notes COM method

Tags: python, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to get a specific document from a Domino view.
The view has 3 columns: Name, Surname, Age.
The problem is, that `Name` is not unique, so I need to get the document that matches 'John' in the `Name` column (1st column) as well as 'Doe' in the second column (`Surname`).

So obviously the following won't work: `doc = view.GetDocumentByKey('John')`

There is a `NotesView` COM [class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDOCUMENTBYKEY_METHOD.html) which contains the `.GetDocumentByKey()` method, which allows one to enter a key array. But I am not able to enter a key array in Python.

I have tried the following:

`doc = view.GetDocumentByKey('John Doe')`

`doc = view.GetDocumentByKey('John, Doe')`

`doc = view.GetDocumentByKey(('John', 'Doe'))`

`doc = view.GetDocumentByKey(['John', 'Doe'])`

But none of them are able to get the needed document.
What is the correct way to pass a key array?

EDIT:
Solution found. There was a sorted hidden column with unique values that I ended up using.

Comment: `GetDocumentByKey` or `GetDocumentsByKey`?

Comment: @PeterWood `GetDocumentByKey`

Comment: Are all columns sorted? All values are checked against sorted columns only, so in your example, the Name and Surname column must be sorted.

Comment: @MichaelRuhnau The first column is definitely sorted. Is there a way I can check if surname is also sorted?

Comment: @ou_snaaksie either you check it in the column design on your own, or you ask the developer of the notes application or you open the view and compare the sorting of values with same name and different Surnames (or the other way aroznd).

Comment: @ou_snaaksie instead of editing the question, it would be better to provide an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found. There was a sorted hidden column with unique values that I ended up using.